# How to debug RESTful services?

Tags: debugging, http, rest

I'm looking for an easy way to debug RESTful services. For example, most webapps can be debugged using your average web browser. Unfortunately that same browser won't allow me to test HTTP PUT, DELETE, and to a certain degree even HTTP POST.

I am not looking to automate tests. I'd like to run new services through a quick sanity check, ideally without having to writing my own client.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use an existing 'REST client' tool that makes it easy to inspect the requests and responses, like [RESTClient](https://github.com/wiztools/rest-client).

Comment: Both of these look like extremely interesting tools, thanks for the pointers!

Comment: i am using first one , works simply nice for me.

Comment: I wrote a REST client plugin called Requester for Sublime Text, https://github.com/kylebebak/Requester. It's inspired by HTTPie and Postman. It's very powerful and easy to use, and it's cross-platform. If you're not in love with your HTTP client it's definitely worth a try.

Answer (score 15):

At my firm we use a variety of different tools and approaches to testing RESTful services:

- We write [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) scripts - essentially a single command saved in a file. One file per resource per method. For PUT and POST, we'll usually have files containing the representations to send alongside the cURL script. For example, for a mailbox resource, we might have a file named `mailbox_post.cmd`, which might contain the line `curl -v -X POST -u username -H 'Content-Type:application/xml' -d @mailbox_post.xml http://service/mailbox`. We like this approach because we end up building a collection of tests which can be run in a batch, or at least passed around between testers, and used for regression testing.
- We use cURL and [RESTClient](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/) for ad-hoc tests
- We have the service serve XHTML by default, so it's browsable, and add forms resources, so the service is actually partially or fully testable using a browser. This was partly inspired by some parts of [RESTful Web Services](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529260/), wherein the authors show that the line between web services and web applications may not need to be as solid and strict as is usually assumed.
- We write functional tests as [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) closures, using the [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org) framework, and run the tests with a test runner Groovy script. This is useful because the tests can be stateful, build on each other, and share variables, when appropriate. We find Restlet's  API to be simple and intuitive, and so easy to write quick HTTP requests and test the responses, and it's even easier when used in Groovy. (I hope to share this technique, including the test runner script, on [our blog](http://blog.arc90.com) soon.)

Answer (score 13):

[Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop), a Google Chrome extension, may be helpful.

Edit years later: Also the website of the url in case Chrome extension link gets changed: [www.postman.com](https://www.postman.com)

Comment: This is a relatively new extension, but simply for the ability to save sets of requests, and manage / share them + a nice interface, I'd recommend it very highly.

Comment: Postman we can upload file requests too as multipart data

Comment: Dead link.  I guess [this app](https://www.postman.com/) is it?  I’m not sure.

Comment: @Guildenstern yes, that's it. I believe it is no more "only a chrome extension", now also a standalone app. You may also use Firecamp, Postwoman, Insomnia etc.

Answer (score 8):

I've found RequestBin useful for debugging REST requests. Post to a unique URL and request data are updated/displayed. Can help in a pinch when other tools are not available.

https://requestbin.com/

Answer (score 5):

A tool I've found useful if you're running OS X Leopard:

[HTTP Client](http://ditchnet.org/httpclient/)

It's a very simple GUI program that allows you to craft http requests to a resource and view the response.

Answer (score 4):

You can use fiddler's [Composer](http://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/composer.asp) to debug [restful services](http://dotnetninja.wordpress.com/2008/05/02/rest-service-with-wcf-and-json/)..

Updated JD 12 sep 2013: *Rest Builder* is now called *Composer*.

Comment: The link to Request Builder above is broken.

Answer (score 4):

`cURL` works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up settling on [POSTMAN](http://www.getpostman.com/)

It supports all REST features I could think of, and the UI is absolutely excellent. The only downside is that it requires Chrome.

Comment: Now it is independent from chrome, U can use it without chrome, means direct installation,

Answer (score 2):

[RESTTest](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5946) for Firefox (an add-on). [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for IE.

Comment: RestTest has been disabled (12 sep 2013)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Soap UI to test my REST API.

It is more complete than any other tools:

- fine debug requests and responses
- automated testing
- all GUI based
- properties and properties transfer to parameterize your tests
- conditional testing
- performance testing

I'm not working for SmartBear.
I was already a big fan of SoapUI while using it for SOAP WebServices.

[image: My SoapUI REST Project]

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using one of the tools in Peter Hilton's response, I would have to say that scripting the tests with LWP or some similar tool may be your only option. You *could* bypass the use of LWP by just opening a socket, sending a raw HTTP request in and examining what you get in return. But as far as I know, there are a dearth of testing tools for this sort of domain-- most look at this problem-space primarily from the lens of a web-site developer, and for them the browser is enough of a testing platform.

Answer (score 0):

I use restclient, available from [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/). It's a simple Java Swing application which supports all HTTP methods, and allows you full control over the HTTP headers, conneg, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to write unit tests for RESTful resources using [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) which comes with a nice REST client. The nice thing is if you implement your RESTful resources using JAX-RS then the Jersey client can reuse the entity providers such as for JAXB/XML/JSON/Atom and so forth - so you can reuse the same objects on the server side as you use on the client side unit test.

For example [here is a unit test case](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/activemq/camel/trunk/components/camel-rest/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/rest/resources/EndpointsTest.java?revision=700513&view=markup) from the [Apache Camel project](http://activemq.apache.org/camel/) which looks up XML payloads from a RESTful resource (using the JAXB object Endpoints). The resource(uri) method is defined in [this base class](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/activemq/camel/trunk/components/camel-rest/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/rest/resources/TestSupport.java?revision=700513&view=markup) which just uses the Jersey client API.

e.g.

```java
clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
client = Client.create(clientConfig);

resource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080");
// lets get the XML as a String
String text = resource("foo").accept("application/xml").get(String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want free tool for the same purpose with additional feature of multipart form data submission it is here http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/restclient-tool/

Answer (score 0):

Firefox's has [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/) plug-in to send different request with methods, parameters, headers etc.

Answer (score 0):

You guys should check [poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) extension for firefox, it's simple and useful enough to use :)

Answer (score 0):

because its totally missing here:
https://luckymarmot.com/paw

Is worth ever penny...