# How do you create a REST client for Java?

Tags: java, rest, client

With JSR 311 and its implementations we have a powerful standard for exposing Java objects via REST. However on the client side there seems to be something missing that is comparable to Apache Axis for SOAP - something that hides the web service and marshals the data transparently back to Java objects.

How do you create Java RESTful clients? Using HTTPConnection and manual parsing of the result? Or specialized clients for e.g. Jersey or Apache CXR?

Comment: Just found [Apache Wink](http://wiki.apache.org/incubator/WinkProposal) in the Apache Incubator. Could be a interesting project for creating REST servers and clients.

Comment: check this out:
http://igorpolevoy.blogspot.com/2011/01/java-rest-with-ease.html thanks igor

Comment: Check out [Resting]( http://code.google.com/p/resting). It promises to invoke REST services and create list of objects from XML/JSON/YAML response in one step.

Comment: Resting has issues with POST requests.

Comment: You can do it in a very simple way with resteasy (by Jboss). I wrote a blog post about [how to develop a Java REST client](http://guidogarcia.net/blog/2012/03/02/how-to-develop-java-rest-client/) if you want a getting started guide. Anyway, there are hundreds of alternatives in Java.

Comment: If you are interesting in Eclipse plugin to generate a java client class from WADL, you can see at link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159881/restful-client-from-wadl/16709008#16709008

Comment: please find my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38724942/6668328

Comment: Why in the world would this be closed as "off topic"?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

This is an old question (2008) so there are many more options now than there were then:

- **Apache CXF** has three different [REST Client options](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html)
- **[Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/)** (mentioned above).
- **[Spring RestTemplate](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate/)** superceded by **Spring WebClient**
- **[Commons HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)** build your own for older Java projects.

**UPDATES (projects still active in 2020):**

- **[Apache HTTP Components (4.2) Fluent adapter](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fluent.html)** - Basic replacement for JDK, used by several other candidates in this list. Better than old Commons HTTP Client 3 and easier to use for building your own REST client. You'll have to use something like [Jackson for JSON parsing](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) support and you can use [HTTP components URIBuilder to construct resource URIs](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e49) similar to Jersey/JAX-RS Rest client. HTTP components also supports NIO but I doubt you will get better performance than BIO given the short requestnature of REST. **Apache HttpComponents 5** has HTTP/2 support.
- **[OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp)** - Basic replacement for JDK, similar to http components, used by several other candidates in this list. Supports newer HTTP protocols (SPDY and HTTP2). Works on Android. Unfortunately it does not offer a true reactor-loop based async option (see Ning and HTTP components above). However if you use the newer HTTP2 protocol this is less of a problem (assuming connection count is  problem).
- **[Ning Async-http-client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client)** - provides NIO support. Previously known as <strike>**[Async-http-client](https://github.com/sonatype/async-http-client)** by Sonatype</strike>.
- **[Feign](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign)**   wrapper for lower level http clients (okhttp, apache httpcomponents). Auto-creates clients based on interface stubs similar to some Jersey and CXF extensions. Strong spring integration.
- **[Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)** - wrapper for lower level http clients (okhttp). Auto-creates clients based on interface stubs similar to some Jersey and CXF extensions.
- **[Volley](https://github.com/google/volley)**     wrapper for jdk http client, by google
- **[google-http](https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client)** wrapper for jdk http client, or apache httpcomponents, by google
- **[Unirest](https://github.com/Kong/unirest-java)**    wrapper for jdk http client, by kong
- **[Resteasy](https://github.com/resteasy)**   JakartaEE wrapper for jdk http client, by jboss, part of jboss framework
- **[jcabi-http](https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-http)** wrapper for apache httpcomponents, part of jcabi collection
- **[restlet](https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java)** wrapper for apache httpcomponents, part of restlet framework
- **[rest-assured](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured)** wrapper with asserts for easy testing

A caveat on picking HTTP/REST clients. Make sure to check what your framework stack is using for an HTTP client, how it does threading, and ideally use the same client if it offers one. That is if your using something like Vert.x or Play you may want to try to use its backing client to participate in whatever bus or reactor loop the framework provides... otherwise be prepared for possibly interesting threading issues.

Comment: Unfortunately Jersey client does not support PATCH method if used with JDK < 8

Comment: as well as Jersey client has some serious memory leaks https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2830

Comment: Unirest is very easy to use but its static design makes it unusable in shared and server environments.

Comment: Unirest is easier but slower as compared to apache HttpClient.

Comment: Here's another new one: [Netflix/feign](https://github.com/Netflix/feign)

Comment: Regarding the **unirest** comment, I would like to add that it currently (end of 2016) looks as if this project is no longer maintained. There is even an [issue](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-java/issues/166) open that asks for a new maintainer.

Comment: Just want to add about NIO and doubts about its performance improvement: as always it depends on how we use the target REST API. Indeed, NIO benefits servers a lot because they handle a lot of requests in parallel. And indeed, for clients, there will be few benefit for short single REST calls. However, same as for servers, NIO will also shine on a client when you issue many requests in parallel. For example, calling GMail API to download 10 messages will consume 10 "units of time" with blocking IO, or 1 "unit of time" with NIO. So, NIO can be very important, *depending* on your usage.

Comment: @Adam Gent     retrofit2 can be compared to jersey with Apache HTTP client ?? can retrofit2 be used to any java reas API (not android) and supports a high performance like jersey? Thank u

Comment: Netflix Feign is also a good alternative https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign

Comment: For those who like [Unirest](http://unirest.io/#java), I've got a [fork](https://github.com/josueeduardo/rest-client) of it  that's currently being actively maintained / updated.

Comment: Jetty,
Netty,
HttpURLConnection in Java 8 and HttpClient in Java 9/10

Comment: @Adam Gent Any information about which one of these rest clients is performant (over HTTPS) in terms of response time?

Comment: _Unirest_ actively uses static configuration. Even cookies are saved as a static state (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/32442318/355438). That's why I strongly recommend NOT to use Unirest!

Comment: would be nice to turn the answer into a community wiki

Answer (score 78):

As I mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165720/how-to-debug-restful-services#166269) I tend to use [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) which implements JAX-RS and comes with a nice REST client. The nice thing is if you implement your RESTful resources using JAX-RS then the Jersey client can reuse the entity providers such as for JAXB/XML/JSON/Atom and so forth - so you can reuse the same objects on the server side as you use on the client side unit test.

For example [here is a unit test case](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/activemq/camel/trunk/components/camel-rest/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/rest/resources/EndpointsTest.java?revision=700513&view=markup) from the [Apache Camel project](http://activemq.apache.org/camel/) which looks up XML payloads from a RESTful resource (using the JAXB object Endpoints). The resource(uri) method is defined in [this base class](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/activemq/camel/trunk/components/camel-rest/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/rest/resources/TestSupport.java?revision=700513&view=markup) which just uses the Jersey client API.

e.g.

```
clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
client = Client.create(clientConfig);

resource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080");
// let's get the XML as a String
String text = resource("foo").accept("application/xml").get(String.class);
```

BTW I hope that future versions of JAX-RS add a nice client-side API along the lines of the one in Jersey.

Comment: Is there a method where we can mention REST service server list in ClientResource, in case the server is down try the next server?

Comment: Just an update, but to address James' 'BTW' comment, the new version of JAX-RS 2.0 will have a client-side API: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Java-REST

Answer (score 69):

You can use the standard Java SE APIs:

```
private void updateCustomer(Customer customer) { 
    try { 
        URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/customers"); 
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
        connection.setDoOutput(true); 
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
        connection.setRequestMethod("PUT"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml"); 

        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream(); 
        jaxbContext.createMarshaller().marshal(customer, os); 
        os.flush(); 

        connection.getResponseCode(); 
        connection.disconnect(); 
    } catch(Exception e) { 
        throw new RuntimeException(e); 
    } 
}
```

Or you can use the REST client APIs provided by JAX-RS implementations such as Jersey. These APIs are easier to use, but require additional jars on your class path.

```
WebResource resource = client.resource("http://www.example.com/customers"); 
ClientResponse response = resource.type("application/xml");).put(ClientResponse.class, "<customer>...</customer."); 
System.out.println(response);
```

For more information see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-55.html

Comment: 13 lines for a simple rest call, **in 2018**, sounds like way too much...

Comment: Once you add error handling and options, it's not really significantly different. If the SE approach seems long, you can always wrap it in a class... :> After two days of debugging JAX-RS library conflicts I'm really fine with 5 extra lines of code to avoid the whole SPI nightmare.

Comment: @ClintEastwood this post was wrote in 2010

Answer (score 17):

If you only wish to invoke a REST service and parse the response you can try out [Rest Assured](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured)

```
// Make a GET request to "/lotto"
String json = get("/lotto").asString()
// Parse the JSON response
List<String> winnderIds = with(json).get("lotto.winners.winnerId");

// Make a POST request to "/shopping"
String xml = post("/shopping").andReturn().body().asString()
// Parse the XML
Node category = with(xml).get("shopping.category[0]");
```

Comment: I found this to be more elegant than many of the other proposed solutions.

Answer (score 10):

You can also check [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org) which has full client-side capabilities, more REST oriented that lower-level libraries such as HttpURLConnection or Apache HTTP Client (which we can leverage as connectors).

Best regards,
Jerome Louvel

Comment: As of 2019-10-24, the link provided returns:  'Restlet Platform has reached end of life.'

Answer (score 7):

You could try [Rapa](https://github.com/harikrishnan83/rapa/wiki/). Let us know your feedback about the same.
And feel free to log issues or expected features.

Comment: Rapa has a really nice interface and few dependencies. A good alternative to RestSharp in the .NET world.

Comment: project looks dead

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to point out 2 more options:

- [Restfulie](http://restfulie.caelum.com.br/), based on the VRaptor web framework, has both server and client side implementations with very good Hypermedia support.
- [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) has a [JAX-RS proxy based client](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.0.GA/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html) implementation.

Comment: Restfulie looks dead

Answer (score 6):

I've recently tried [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) Library from square, Its great and you can call your rest API very easily. 
Annotation based configuration allows us to get rid of lot of boiler plate coding.

Answer (score 6):

OkHttp is lightweight and powerful when combined with Retrofit as well.  This works well for general Java use as well as on Android.

**OkHttp**: http://square.github.io/okhttp/

```
public static final MediaType JSON
    = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
  RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .post(body)
      .build();
  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

**Retrofit**: http://square.github.io/retrofit/

```
public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("/users/{user}/repos")
  Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I use Apache HTTPClient to handle all the HTTP side of things.

I write XML SAX parsers for the XML content that parses the XML into your object model. I believe that Axis2 also exposes XML -> Model methods (Axis 1 hid this part, annoyingly). XML generators are trivially simple.

It doesn't take long to code, and is quite efficient, in my opinion.

Comment: In my opinion this is the worst way to do REST. Manually handling serialization in Java is a waste of time when you have so many options like JAXB and Jackson. Even loading the whole document and using XPath is marginally slower than SAX and nothing compared to getting the XML (network speed).

Comment: I agree too, and I wrote the original comment. Back then I had a desire for control of the deserialisation, but nowadays I would use Jackson and decently annotated model classes.

Answer (score 4):

Since no one mentioned, here is another one: [Feign](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign), which is used by [Spring Cloud](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/).

Answer (score 3):

Though its simple to create a HTTP client and make a reuest. But if you want to make use of some auto generated clients,  You can make use of WADL to describe and generate code.

You can use [RestDescribe](http://tomayac.de/rest-describe/latest/RestDescribe.html) to generate and compile WSDL, you can generate clients in php, ruby, python, java and C# using this. It generates clean code and there is a good change that you have to tweak it a bit after code generation, you can find good documentation and underlying thoughts behind the tool [here](https://docs.google.com/document/edit?id=1uydmzsDFIiw8OsoMdk5v_s1VW7wrujUmGdUU2zge0fs).

There are few interesting and useful [WADL tools](http://wintermuteblog.blogspot.com/2010/01/wadl-toolbox.html) mentioned on wintermute.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a library that maps a java interface to a remote JSON REST service:

https://github.com/ggeorgovassilis/spring-rest-invoker

```
public interface BookService {
   @RequestMapping("/volumes")
   QueryResult findBooksByTitle(@RequestParam("q") String q);

   @RequestMapping("/volumes/{id}")
   Item findBookById(@PathVariable("id") String id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Examples of Jersey Rest client

Adding the dependency :

```
<!-- Jersey -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
    
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
```

For `GetMethod` and passing two parameters:

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource1 = client
                        .resource("http://localhost:10102/NewsTickerServices/AddGroup/"
                                + userN + "/" + groupName);

ClientResponse response1 = webResource1.get(ClientResponse.class);
System.out.println("responser is" + response1);
```

`GetMethod` passing one parameter and getting a response of type `List` :

```
Client client = Client.create();
 
WebResource webResource1 = client
                    .resource("http://localhost:10102/NewsTickerServices/GetAssignedUser/"+grpName);    
//value changed
String response1 = webResource1.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
 
List <String > Assignedlist = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray jsonArr2 = new JSONArray(response1);
for (int i =0;i<jsonArr2.length();i++){
        
    Assignedlist.add(jsonArr2.getString(i));    
}
```

Above it returns a list that we are accepting as a `List` object and then converts it to `JSONArray` and then from `JSONArray` to `List`.

`Post` request passing `JSONObject` as a parameter:

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client
            .resource("http://localhost:10102/NewsTickerServices/CreateJUser");
// value added

ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, mapper.writeValueAsString(user));

if (response.getStatus() == 500) {

    context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("User already exist "));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used [RestAssured](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2019/11/restassured-tutorial.html) most of the time to parse rest service response and test the services. Apart from Rest Assured, I used below libraries too to communicate with Resful services.

a. [Jersey Rest Client](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2015/08/jersey-rest-client-api-tutorial.html)

b. [Spring RestTemplate](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2019/09/spring-resttemplate-tutorial.html)

c. [Apache HTTP Client](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2015/10/apache-http-client-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at http-rest-client

https://github.com/g00dnatur3/http-rest-client

Here is a simple example:

```
RestClient client = RestClient.builder().build();
String geocoderUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json"
Map<String, String> params = Maps.newHashMap();
params.put("address", "beverly hills 90210");
params.put("sensor", "false");
JsonNode node = client.get(geocoderUrl, params, JsonNode.class);
```

The library takes care of json serialization and binding for you.

Here is another example,

```
RestClient client = RestClient.builder().build();
String url = ...
Person person = ...
Header header = client.create(url, person);
if (header != null) System.out.println("Location header is:" + header.value());
```

And one last example,

```
RestClient client = RestClient.builder().build();
String url = ...
Person person = client.get(url, null, Person.class); //no queryParams
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request I like their simplicity and the way examples are shown, but mostly I was sold when I read:

> What are the dependencies?
>
> None. The goal of this library is to be a single class class with some inner static classes. The test project does require Jetty in order to test requests against an actual HTTP server implementation.

which sorted out some problems on a java 1.6 project. As for decoding json into objects [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) is just invincible :)

Comment: project looks dead, no commits since 2015.