# How do I connect to the IBM WebSphere MQ without having the IBM WebSphere MQ Client installed on the client machine?

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I was looking for something to enable me to do this but couldn't find much.

I followed the steps described in the following answer to another question -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23920904/3299246

but that isn't working. I get a lot of errors saying the files/dependencies were not found.

Is there any way I can connect to the MQ without having the client installed?

Thanks.

Comment: Given the additional information that this is for Mobile, why not use any .Net MQTT compatible library and run the MQXR component with the QMgr?

Comment: Would you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new answer in light of the revelation that this is for mobile.  You don't say whether this is for Windows Phone or Surface.  I am not familiar enough with Surface, but IBM might even have a version of the MQ client that will work on it.  Or maybe not.

Whether you are using Windows Phone for mobile or a Surface device, the device should not have a problem connecting to a WCF Service which connects to WMQ.  **James the Integration Guy** has done a bit of work with this, and here's a blog post that might contain some ideas for you:

[Using .NET WCF to connect to WebSphere MQ](http://www.jamestheintegrationguy.com/using-net-wcf-to-connect-to-websphere-mq/)

Unfortunately, the blog appears to be inactive, so there may be no update on his progress.

ETA: Just to expand on my comment, Android can be made to connect to a WCF Service.  Some links:

- [Lessons Learned: Getting Android to Connect to a WCF Service](http://www.ideatoappster.com/lessons-learned-getting-android-to-connect-to-a-wcf-service/)
- [How to connect to a wcf Service with Android - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133006/how-to-connect-to-a-wcf-service-with-android)
- [Connect to WCF service through android - Android Forums](http://androidforums.com/application-development/805165-connect-wcf-service-through-android.html)

Comment: Its for Android AND WP. :)

Comment: @doodla, I would bet that there are libraries somewhere that would enable Android to connect to a WCF Service.  Not being an Android guy I have no idea where to look, though.

Answer (score 0):

Afraid not officially... At the moment, my understanding is to run MQ .NET applications you need to have the MQ Client (or Server) installed which provides the .NET capability (either through the file system or via the GAC). You can run in fully managed mode, avoiding the need for calling through the C runtime components for the client functionality.

With some releases of MQ you are able to extract out just the files you need (its not just one file!) and be able to run in fully managed mode, but I would not recommend it... Feel free to raise a requirement with IBM

Comment: Any options unofficially? I tried using IKVM but that gives me some errors. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. I'm not at all familiar with WMQ. The project was dropped in my lap. Anything at all will help.

Comment: If you are determined to use the .net C# interfaces, nothing currently (what used to work doesnt in more recent MQs). 

Note as a direct answer to your question other options include:
- "WebSphere MQ bridge for HTTP" which enables clients without MQ to do soem basic operations - just bear in mind it needs special things set up on the server side (q033180_ in docs). 
- If you dont need c# and could use Java, look at the redistributable "All Client jar" which is new for 8.0.0.1 (released yesterday), which gives you the jar(s) you need to hava a java app without needing full client install

Comment: Having also read your comments on another answer, if you are targetting mobile then you ought to look at the mqtt (Telemetry) clients / support, which is aimed for that kind of market

Answer (score 0):

You *could* take your life in your own hands and try using [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net) to convert the pure Java WebSphere MQ libraries to .Net IL. I have never tried it with WebSphere MQ Java libraries specifically, but I have had a 96% success rate with many other Java libs.

Even if this works.... **it will be unsupported**.

Comment: I did just that. Unfortunately, one of the jar files gave massive errors I can't list here as they appeared in console when the conversion was being done. At first, I didn't realize that they were errors, but when I converted another jar file, there wasn't as much text.

Comment: I'm fine with unsupported.

Comment: Eew...  It can be a bit tricky, especially when you have multiple interdependent jars. Google for the ikvm Ant task if you want to pursue this.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer that comes to my mind is actually a question: Why on earth would you want to try to do this?

The WMQ client is very unintrusive and there really isn't a good reason to do without it.  It's free to use and so cost is not an issue.  Have you discovered some niche environment for which IBM has failed to provide a version of the client?  Unless this is the case I suggest you abandon this notion.

Comment: Need to connect via Mobile.

Comment: Ah ha!  Yes, @doodla, now it comes clear.  You might want to indicate this in your question -- it's important, and none of the answers so far seem to be aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the integration of mobile to WebSphere MQ that I'm aware of uses MQTT and the WebSphere MQ MQXR component.  MQXR (for Extended Reach) is an MQTT broker running as a sub-process of the QMgr.  It provides the full MQTT broker implementation and optionally bridges between MQTT and the QMgr.

Please see the MQ Knowledge Center for details:

[Administering WebSphere MQ Telemetry](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.adm.doc/q021250_.htm)