# Android 3 calling WCF REST

Tags: android, .net, wcf

I'd like to create a RESTful WCF service and then call it from an Android 3.2 or 4.0 app. I have this sample [here](http://fszlin.dymetis.com/post/2010/05/10/Comsuming-WCF-Services-With-Android.aspx), but it dates back to May 2010. I'd like to know if that is still the best way of doing this?

The WCF part is OK, I can handle it (since I'm a .NET guy), but I'm looking for the best (both performance and security) way of calling the service.

If you have any links, samples or even books to suggest, I'd be more than happy.

Comment: Hi, i'm doing the same, and dont know from where to begin. the sample link is not available anymore. Do you still have the sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this https://sites.google.com/site/androidosbeginning/cosuming-restful-webservice-in-android

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can get the WSDL from the WCF service, you should be able to interact with it using something like AXIS for Java and use wsdl2java to generate the client stub to interact with the service... though AXIS is relatively heavy to use on Android devices.  I've never done anything like that with Android, but that's how it's done with Java.  Perhaps there are some lighter-weight libraries you can use.

Here's a similar post: [How to Consume WCF Service with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669764/how-to-consume-wcf-service-with-android)