# Hosting a wcf application and accessing it from an Android device, how to do this?

Tags: android

How to host a wcf application in iis and access it from Android device to get a json? I need to host a wcf application in iis and access it through the android device, how can this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Consume WCF Service with Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669764/how-to-consume-wcf-service-with-android)

Comment: But I have not yet been possible to host the WCF service using IIS, that is the main issue.

Comment: Then your question should be `How to host and WCF service using IIS?`. Question you can easily find the answer... as there are tons of tutorials on the Internet about this. After that, your second question will be `How to access it from Android?`, with the answer in the stackoverflow question I indicated. Please read the rules of stackoverflow. You should really ask one question per question. And do a little search before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

There are many tutorials for this .. I am putting down a list of tutorials for you ..

1)http://romenlaw.blogspot.in/2008/08/consuming-web-services-from-android.html

2)http://www.kevingao.net/wcf-java-interop

Some code snippets from some stackoverflow answers

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://mycompany.com/LoginService")]
public interface ILoginService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Login(string username, string password);
}
The implementation of the service could look like this:

public class LoginService : ILoginService
{
    public string Login(string username, string password)
    {
        // Do something with username, password to get/create sessionId
        string sessionId = "12345678";

        return sessionId;
    }
}
You can host this as a windows service using a ServiceHost, or you can host it in IIS like a normal ASP.NET web (service) application. There are a lot of tutorials out there for both of these.

The WCF service config might look like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>


    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="LoginServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <services>
            <service name="WcfTest.LoginService"
                     behaviorConfiguration="LoginServiceBehavior" >
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://somesite.com:55555/LoginService/" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
                <endpoint name="LoginService"
                          address=""
                          binding="basicHttpBinding"
                          contract="WcfTest.ILoginService" />

                <endpoint name="LoginServiceMex"
                          address="mex"
                          binding="mexHttpBinding"
                          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Courtesy : [How to Consume WCF Service with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669764/how-to-consume-wcf-service-with-android)

Also on code project there is nice tutorial

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/358867/WCF-and-Android-Part-I

If you done with WCF part then the above link would not be that useful for you, the next part will be pretty much useful for

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361107/WCF-and-Android-Part-II