# using ws2007httpbinding security in android ksoap2

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

i've webservice as follows

```
<ws2007HttpBinding>
            <binding name="ws2007HttpBinding" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </ws2007HttpBinding>
```

i'm provided with an username,password and a X509 certificate..i'm having trouble with configuring the soap envelope.. what information to provide and what not..what the format of the envelope should be?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ws2007HttpBinding` - it's unfeasibly hard to consume it in Java/Android. Better expose additional endpoint for the same service, using [basicHttpBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669764/how-to-consume-wcf-service-with-android).

You can try the [wsdl2ksoap](https://code.google.com/p/wsdl2ksoap/) project, but it's unlikely it will be able to generate correct classes ofr this type of binding.

Comment: its configured by my client and i'm asked to fetch services from it.. i'm new to soap so i need an example

Comment: Tell the client it will cost him either several years of paying you for development OR just a simple configuration change :)