# How does one set up a proxy and test with browsermob-proxy?

Tags: api, rest, batch-file, proxy

My apologies ahead of time for being a complete noob, and not having as specific a question as I should...but I'm not sure where to start!

I've installed browsermob-proxy, ran the browsermob-proxy batch file to initiate the proxy...but have no idea where to go now!

This is the best tutorial I could find...please scroll to REST API section

https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy

I know I need to communicate with the application through the API...but I don't understand what language the sample commands are in (is it linux shell scripting)? Can this API be executed in jQuery or any other language with POST/PUT/DELETE capabilites? If so...how do these commands translate? Does anyone know of a better way of using browsermob-proxy?

Any insights are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The samples are using curl to call the APIs.  It is just a command line lib available on various platforms to make http (and other) requests..I think the REST APIs should be able to be invoked by most of the languages...I have no experience with jQuery..so not sure

I have used browsermob-proxy with Selenium by adding it as a dependency to my maven project as has been highlighted in the later part of the tutorial that you are referring to.

I am not invoking the APIs but I believe there should be plenty of libraries available in Java to call REST APIs..some links on googlin :
[RESTful call in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913502/restful-call-in-java)

[Java API for invoking REST services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289704/java-api-for-invoking-rest-services)

Hope it helps answer part of your question..