# Protocol Buffers Java RPC Stack

Tags: java, rpc, protocols, protocol-buffers

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers) Wikipedia entry:

*"Protocol Buffers is very similar to Facebook’s Thrift protocol, except it does not include a concrete RPC stack to use for defined services. Since Protocol Buffers was open sourced, a number of RPC stacks have emerged to fill this gap."*

However, there are no examples of RPC stacks cited.  Can anyone suggest a Java-based implementation of an RPC stack?

Comment: I am really not very sure, but recently I had come across this one from ZeroC

http://www.zeroc.com/labs/protobuf/download.html

Comment: Have a look at the following solution which adds an RPC implementation specifically to ProtocolBuffers: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-rpc-pro/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want Java-based RPC stack, it's [RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation). However, it doesn't work well cross platform.

I've been using ProtoBuf to do RPC. You can pretty much simulate an RPC stack by wrapping a protobuf message inside another protobuf, which defines the services or calls. Find my answer to this question for details,

[Google Protocol Buffers and HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425912/google-protocol-buffers-and-http)

Thrift looks like a very good alternative if you want support more platforms like PHP, Ruby, C# etc. However, it looks very complex to me compared to ProtoBuf.

Answer (score 4):

Google has open sourced their RPC framework [gRPC](http://www.grpc.io/), which uses Protocol Buffers to define the service and messages. gRPC is cross-platform with support for C, C++, C#, Java, Go, Node.js, Python, Ruby, Objective-C and PHP.

gRPC is based on the HTTP/2 standard that enables new capabilities such as bidirectional streaming, flow control, header compression and multiplexed connections.

Comment: Thanks; this is really really useful!

Comment: unfortunately gRPC does NOT support C.