# What is the correct Protobuf content type?

Tags: mime-types, protocol-buffers, content-type

JSON has [`application/json`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type) as a standard. For protobuf some people use [`application/x-protobuf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190329/protocol-buffers-mime-problem), but I saw something as odd as [`application/vnd.google.protobuf`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/VAoJ-HtgpAI) being proposed. Do we have an RFC or some other standard that I can use as a reference for this?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/VAoJ-HtgpAI is probably where the vnd one comes from; no, I'm not aware of any change since that discussion, and no: I'm not aware of any standard

Comment: looks like protorpc switched to `application/octet-stream`: https://github.com/google/protorpc/commit/eb03145a6a7c72ae6cc43867d9635a5b8d8c4545

Comment: there *is* an IEFT draft https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-rfernando-protocol-buffers-00 that suggests `application/protobuf`, however: that is only a draft and kinda looks like it didn't go anywhere and is now expired

Comment: It most cases, knowing that some data is a protobuf isn't particularly useful; if you want to know the type at all, you want to know what protobuf type it is. So really, every user of protobuf needs their own content-type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Protocol Buffers and HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425912/google-protocol-buffers-and-http)

Comment: @KentonVarda Knowing data is protobuf is useful, even without identifying the nature of the messages. For example, consider the value of content type in content negotiation between XML or JSON - even though they're both useless if you can't interpret their contents. It's equally useful for more than two choices, e.g. XML or protobuf or JSON or LISP (or would it be LISPON?). :-)

Answer (score 46):

There's an [expired IETF proposal](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-rfernando-protocol-buffers-00) that suggests `application/protobuf`. It does not address the question how the receiving side could determine the particular message type. Previous discussions suggested using a parameter to specify package and message, e.g. `application/protobuf; proto=org.some.Message`

In practice, the types you listed seem to be indeed the ones in use, for example the monitoring system [Prometheus uses `application/vnd.google.protobuf`](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/), and the [Charles web debugging proxy recognizes `application/x-protobuf; messageType="x.y.Z"`](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/protocol-buffers/).

Comment: What is the implication of the protobuf RFC being expired?

Comment: Prometheus no longer supports protobuf: https://github.com/OpenObservability/OpenMetrics/blob/master/markdown/protobuf_vs_text.md

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of being overly pedantic, the other answers only make sense if we're assuming that "protobuf content type" means the standard wire format for protos.

Content types should map to encoding schemes, and there are multiple encoding schemes for protos. The wire format is the most common and important one, but there's also [text format](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.text_format), and potentially others. That being said, I am unable to find any standard content type for proto text format, so I don't know of any other options to add here.

Protos are just a way of describing schema, and are not tightly coupled with any particular way of encoding data in that schema.

Answer (score 0):

The Content-Type representation header is used to indicate the original media type of the resource (prior to any content encoding applied for sending). Meanwhile, protobuf is serialization/de-serialization schema/library.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare have elected to use application/x-protobuf

https://developers.cloudflare.com/support/speed/optimization-file-size/what-will-cloudflare-compress/

So if you want to use cloudflare compression you need to specify that no application/protobuf