# MIME type for Flatbuffers?

Tags: http, serialization, deserialization, flatbuffers

I've searched to find the proper MIME type for flatbuffers but I can't seem to find any. No mention of it on their documentation either.

The project page: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is none. The correct mime type to use is `application/octet-stream`.

I don't think creating one would make sense either, since a naked FlatBuffer (without knowledge of its schema) cannot be parsed (unlike JSON), it is an opaque binary file. `application/flatbuffer` (if it existed) is barely more useful than `application/octet-stream`.

You need the schema before the file becomes readable, and I don't think mime types have a way to specify the schema name.. though I suppose `flatbuffers/schema-name` would be cool, if whatever standards body governs mime types would allow it :)

Comment: I like the `flatbuffers/schema-name` suggestion. Since my use case is not a public facing api, I might make use of that information. I wasnt expecting any standard for this because of the nature of flatbuffers, but I still wanted to make sure there are no standards I was missing. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

There is a similar question for protocol buffers, with a useful answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48051331/761177

For flatbuffers something like application/x-flatbuffers;schema=x.y.z might be appropriate, where x.y.z is the namespace declared in your schema.