# How to send a trace data to an OTLP gRPC endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, grpc, open-telemetry

Noob question here. I'm getting the data from AWS X-Ray and trying to send it to an endpoint of OTLP.

Sample Data:

```json
{
    "id": "12345678901233456",
    "name": "asdfghjkl",
    "start_time": 1.666058486989E9,
    "trace_id": "1-adg346-dhagjkh348762834jah37846f",
    "end_time": 1.666058487934E9
}
```

1. Created a proto for AWS X-Ray segment document format
2. Marshaling the data to send it to the OTLP endpoint
3. Creating requests using http.NewRequestWithContext
4. Added a header of `Content-Type: application/json`

I'm still quite new to this and confused about how to do it properly. Since I'm a beginner in AWS, protobuf, and gRPC. It is still unable to send the data to the OTLP receiver for it to be processed.

Is there something wrong with how I'm doing it? Can someone give me some advice or help me to do it properly? Is there a format that I need to follow? How the data be sent should look?

Comment: GRPC is binary format, so `Content-Type: application/json` is really not good header (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505408/what-is-the-correct-protobuf-content-type). You can use OTLP HTTP protocol (not OTLP GRPC protocol) to send data in json format, but used collector must support it + JSON over OTLP HTTP is experimental implementation officialy.

Comment: I tried updating my code to use the gRPC as it is one of the requirements. Now it is using `application/x-protobuf` and I'm using `grpc.Dial`. I'm following a sample to connect and export. @JanGaraj

Here's the file: [client.go](https://github.com/tigrannajaryan/exp-otelproto/blob/master/protoimpls/grpc_unary/client.go#L13)