# HttpClient vs Spring Rest Template?

Tags: java, spring, rest, httpclient

What's the best way to make a REST call?

Should I use `Apache Http Client` or Should I use `Spring Rest Template`.

On what basis I can decide which one I should go for?

I need to make a call to this url-

`http://localhost:8080/service/Service/v1/get/USERID=10000/profile.ACCOUNT.SERVICE"`

And after getting the response back, I just need to see whether that response contains any particular string or not.

Comment: See the answer by @skaffman in this question - [spring-integration-or-apache-http-client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850344/spring-integration-or-apache-http-client).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Spring `RestTemplate` follows the pattern for all the *Template classes within the core Spring framework and the various sub-frameworks: `JdbcTemplate`, `HibernateTemplate`, `WebServiceTemplate` etc etc.

The idea of all of these Template classes is to reduce the boilerplate code (exception handling, repetitive stuff and concentrate on your business logic). I would definitely use it over the simple `HttpClient`.

To get the class you'll need the [spring-web](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web/3.2.1.RELEASE) dependency.

Comment: Thanks abalogh for the suggestion, I was also planning to use RestTemplate. I am working with Eclipse and with Java project. How can I add RestTemplate libraries in my project? When I am putting `RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate()`. It is showing, it cannot be resolved to a type.