# Create Restful Client Consumer with Tomcat

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jakarta-ee, annotations

I am using Apache tomcat 6.0.20
I want to create Client To Consume RESTFul Web Service(using GET)

I know I can do it via the old fashion way with URLConnection (regular GET request).

But I wonder is there any way of doing it differently? maybe with Annotations?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end I chose to use the JAVA SE API in the old and fashion way:

```
public void getRestfullMethod(...) throws IOException
  {
        String temp = null;

        //Build the request data.
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer (..)
        buf.append("&system=").append ("someVal");

        String urlStr = buf.toString ();

        //Send the request.
        URL url = new URL (urlStr);
      URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

      //Return the response.
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (con.getInputStream ()));
        String inputLine = null;

        buf = new StringBuffer ();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine ()) != null)
              buf.append (inputLine);
        in.close ();

  }
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this article http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-137171.html will give you good guidance how to act in both directions.

Comment: Yes but this is Oracle. I talk about Apache tomcat. is there capability to use Annotations for rest client there?

Comment: We talk about java here. No matter oracle or apache.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using the API of spring. The connection handling for example is handled already within the RestTemplate class. Have a look to http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-client-access.

Comment: Hi, I am not using Spring framework, so I assume I cant use that API. thanks.

Comment: In this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221442/rest-clients-for-java thread are some non-spring APIs like Jersey mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Using NetBeans 7 there is the possibility to have RESTFul web services created with a simple wizard (with Jersey API): http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html . This approach uses annotations.

Comment: But is creating the service or the client?