# How to convert object to query string with spring (or anything else)?

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc

Is there a way to convert object to query parameters of GET request?
Some kind of serializer that converts NameValuePair object to name=aaa&value=bbb, so that string can be attached to the GET request.

In other words, I'm looking for a library that takes
1. url (`http://localhost/bla`)
2. Object:
`public class Obj {

 String id;

 List<NameValuePair> entities;

}`
And converts it to:
`http://localhost/bla?id=abc&entities[0].name=aaa&entities[0].value=bbb`

Spring RestTemplate is not what I'm looking for as it does all  other things except converting object to parameters string.

Comment: If you are using RESTFUL communication yes.

Comment: you can find a simple example at http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/

Comment: Actually I asked about the opposite. I want to write java client that can sent requests to such a controller. I need to convert an object into parameters.

Comment: in that case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221442/rest-clients-for-java

Answer (score 9):

```
// object to Map
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, String> map = objectMapper.convertValue(obj, new TypeReference<Map<String,String>>() {});

// Map to MultiValueMap
LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> linkedMultiValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.entrySet().forEach(e -> linkedMultiValueMap.add(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));

// call RestTemplate.exchange
return getRestTemplate().exchange(
        uriBuilder().path("your-path").queryParams(linkedMultiValueMap).build().toUri(),
        HttpMethod.GET,
        null,
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<YourTypes>>() {}).getBody();
```

Answer (score 1):

use com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client:

```
Client.create().resource("url").queryParam(key, value).get()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. convert an Object to a Map
2. Convert Map to QueryString

```java
package util;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.util.Map;

public class ObjectConvertUtil {
    // convert Object to queryString 
    public static String toQS(Object object){

        // Object --> map
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> map =
                objectMapper.convertValue(
                        object, Map.class);


        StringBuilder qs = new StringBuilder();
        for (String key : map.keySet()){

            if (map.get(key) == null){
                continue;
            }
            // key=value&
            qs.append(key);
            qs.append("=");
            qs.append(map.get(key));
            qs.append("&");
        }

        // delete last '&'
        if (qs.length() != 0) {
            qs.deleteCharAt(qs.length() - 1);
        }
        return qs.toString();
    }
}
```

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
```