# Unit testing code that requires Request & Framework context

Tags: java, http, testing, junit, request

I am working in an Apache sling based environment. Much of my code-base can be unit tested "normally" at compile using Junit tests.

There is a subset of functionality that requires the context of a HTTP request being passed in through the Framework to work properly, and the effort for Mock all the Framework provided objects that i rely on is far too difficult.

My current approach during my test build cycle is:
1) Junit test everything I can using standard JUnit tests
2) Compile and deploy the code to my local instance
3) Make HTTP requests to specific "test" resources on my local instance that run a "test" and return some value
4) Check the return value against the expected value 
(repeat 3-4)

I am trying to figure out how to most effectively define my tests outside the platform (from where I am issuing the HTTP requests) and execute them from the context of my local instance.

Thoughts on the best way to structure and execute a test suite give these requirements?

Answer (score 0):

What your trying to do I believe is run what are normally called "Integration Tests" or "Acceptance Tests". Although the line is blurry what makes an integration test/acceptance test is that they generally involve multiple components where as a unit test should only focus on one component and mock everything.

Mybest recommendation is you create a separate test suite that will start your sling server (on a predefined port) and then run a bunch of test that will make RESTful calls to your server.

I recommend you use either [Spring Rest Template or Jersey's Rest Client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/221763/318174) with JUnit. Your build script will have to start the server. Many people use [Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/) (unfortuanately the cargo site is down right now) to do that.

Slowly you'll make a library and convenience fixtures/methods/objects so that it gets easier.

Comment: right, i am blurring the lines a little. The problem is that every method in my class depends on the framework, so i cannot unit test my class *at all* right now. What I'd like to do is be able to make requests http://local:9000/test/myclass?exec=obj.getProperty("foo") -- and in the servlet responsible for myclass would declare the obj, and then execute the param value of "exec" against it. (I understand this is dangerous in the wrong env). I may end up making a JSP for each method on the class that merely prints out the return val.

Comment: Also, Im happy making RESTful calls to my server (dev or integration dev), I was looking for a nice concise way to executes tests against each method, without being overly verbose and creating a extra-tight coupling between my test suite and the env running the test.