# How to access Google Drive shared link programmatically?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

Google Drive allows you to share files using direct links. Is there a way to access a Google Drive file using that link within a web application (written in Java and JSP)? Which Google APIs should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Start with [Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/) page. It contains best practices and samples in 5 programmign languagues, including [Java](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/java).

Google Drive is using [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) pattern to operate on the files. Any Java REST client library should be enough - see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221442/rest-clients-for-java).

Comment: The Google Drive Java sample involves creating an App Engine, authorization, registering apps, etc., is there a straightforward way of accessing a shared link within Java?