# Get driveId from Google drive link programmatically

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have a shared Google Drive Link (shared within company), pointing to a particular folder in Drive.

How could I get driveId of this folder, programmatically in my Android app?  (I am not the owner, I just have ReadOnly access-'Can View' for this folder).

I can evaluate driveId of folders in Drive folders shared with me (using Google Drive sdk of Google Play services).
But I am clueless about how to proceed for getting driveId from shared link.
Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Before anyone points, I have gone through seemingly related question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084046/how-to-access-google-drive-shared-link-programmatically)  ,   but this seeks a web application, and has no accepted answer (only a vague direction pointer).