# How to Trigger from one rest web service to another?

Tags: java

I have written a rest web service for fire panel and for a pubic address system. If there is a possibility for fire in a particular location then it has to send message to public address system. For that I have to trigger from fire panel service to public address system service. How can I do this?

Comment: Youneed to gove more details about the APIs to the services and show what you have attempted.

Answer (score 2):

If you can write a class which executes a call to a `REST web service` and returns a result, then of course you can incorporate that class into any application, even a `REST` style service

Like a regular call to a `REST web service`, in the body of the service you must create an instance of the client to call the second web service.

Comment: Have you got your answer

Comment: yeah thank you Rais.I got it and done with that.

Comment: Great, if you like the answer then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Your fire alarm service is just another rest client for the public address system service. You can use any REST client / HTTP client to make calls to the other service. There is nothing special about this.

Here's a related question about using REST clients - [Rest clients for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221442/rest-clients-for-java)