# Make RESTful call in a task in jBPM

Tags: jbpm, bpmn

Based on the input of a user task I want to make a RESTful call. Please suggest me a possibility of achieving this in jBPM?

Comment: What do you mean by jBPM? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221442/rest-clients-for-java

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

http://www.jboss.org/resteasy