# The newbie world of Restful and SOAP services in Java

Tags: rest, soap, java-ee-6, restful-url

As a newbie, I need a bit of help with this question. Perhaps, a pointer to a tutorial as well.

I have a restful service that gets a student's name  and a soap service that receives the name as a parameter and returns the student's location. Now, I want to create a final service from both combined such that both SOAP and Restful Services can use my service by . How would i go about this in Java?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a wsdl, you can generate client code to invoke the SOAP service. You can invoke REST services in a variety of ways. If there is a WADL, then you can generate code, otherwise find a good [rest client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221442/rest-clients-for-java/) for java and use that in your assembly service.