# Integrating SugarCRM with Java

Tags: java, rest, sugarcrm

I am new to SugarCRM system. I want to integrate SugarCRM with Java. Please let me know how can I access Rest Webservice (SugarCRM API) using JAVA.

Please help.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You asked a similar question yesterday, which was put on hold. The scope of what you are asking is simply too broad. Please consult http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to ask good questions on SO, as well as http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask for advice on what sorts of questions are not a good fit for SO (like this one).

Answer (score 0):

You should use REST clients for Java and refer to SugarCRM API documents for detailed usage, currently the question is vague and doesn't contain any specific problem.

On using REST client, I suggest you to check for duplicates like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221442/rest-clients-for-java).

Comment: I am using "https://bhf.trial.sugarcrm.eu/rest/v10/oauth2/token" as a URL fand sending { "grant_type":"password", 
 "client_id":"44d03a06-a9cc-6586-334d4bd", 
 "client_secret":"", 
 "username":"admin", 
 "password":"Password", 
 "platform":"base" 
}
As a parameter but I am getting "Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing" as a error. Plz help.

Comment: I got 404 on URL you provided and wasn't been able to find any parameter like `grant_type` in [API examples](https://github.com/sugarcrm/sugarcrm_dev/blob/master/tests/service/RESTAPI4Test.php). What SugarCRM version are you using?

Comment: Its "SugarCRM Enterprise, Version 7.6.1.0 (Build 1163)" version. I am using trial version of SugarCRM. This is a updated URL "https://bhfegp7836.trial.sugarcrm.eu/rest/v10/oauth2/token".
You can test this on SoapUi or Postman.