# Which resteasy-client is suitable for Jboss 6.4 EAP?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, resteasy

I'm developing REST application on JBoss and I need to use some JAX-RS http client implemention. I'm using Jboss 6.4 EAP. [Here](https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673) i found that i need `2.3.10.Final` version of `resteasy-jaxrs` and `resteasy-jackson-provider`.

I'm trying to use `resteasy-client` but i'm not sure if it's even possible. [Here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-client) i can't find any version like my other resteasy related versions.
Moreover 3.x version of `resteasy-client` has dependency to `resteasy-jaxrx` in 3.x version and it causes `RESTEASY001745: Unable to find a public constructor for class org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher`
 exception. Of course i can exclude `resteasy-jaxrx` form `resteasy-client` but it's not a solution. Another exception will appear (class not found `HeaderValueProcessor.java`)

So it is possible to use resteasy client in JBoss 6.4 EAP ?

Comment: It doesn't matter what rest client you use to connect to a rest service, regardless of what platform the client is running on. There should be plenty of tutorials on using `resteasy` client jars.

Comment: @Nicholas I'm affraid in this case it does matter. Note that `resteasy-jaxrx` is provided by server (this dependency has `provided` scope in `pom.xml`). So server which i'm using provides me `resteasy-jaxrs` in  `2.3.10.Final` version but any`resteasy-client` has  dependency to `resteasy-jaxrs` in other version (3.x). Here is the conflict. I can't find `resteasy-client` for `2.3.10.Final`. 

If you have such tutorial, please provide link.

Comment: So are you trying to run the client within the rest service or just connect to the service from anywhere?

Comment: The first one. I'm trying to connect form service to other service.

Comment: Yea, ok, I see what you're getting at. There was no resteasy client prior to version 3.X. What you can do, which is probably best, is to use another jax-rs provider for your client calls so there is no conflict between jars used your client and the server's jars. Apache CFX, Jersey, etc, here is a stackoverflow article on [Rest clients for Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221442/rest-clients-for-java)

Comment: Just as I thought. I needed confirmation. I will try to use Jerey. I hope those two implementations won't beats each other. Thanks for your help. I appreciate.

Answer (score 5):

No, it seems there isn't resteasy-client.jar for JBoss EAP 6.4. As you mentioned, that version of JBoss use resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final.jar and there is not resteasy-client prior to resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.x.jar version.

Hope this help to save time to anyone who has to use EAP 6.4.