# Delete rest with parameters

Tags: java, json, rest, http, http-delete

I need to write this REST request in java using Httpdelete or any other library.

```
curl -X DELETE -d '{"ruleid":"1" }' http://192.168.1.1:8080/wm/acl/rules/json
```

I couldn't find a way to parse the Json data !

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like others said, it is unusual that a DELETE request contains a body. But it is not strictly impossible as long as the server supports it.

There are many ways to build a REST Client in Java (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5024571/1018443). A common way is to use Jersey 2.

In Jersey 2, the `.delete()` method does not contain a parameter for the body entity. But you can use `.build` to create a DELETE request with a body. Here is an example:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientProperties;

public class RestClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model model = new Model();

        ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
        config.property(ClientProperties.SUPPRESS_HTTP_COMPLIANCE_VALIDATION, true);
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
        WebTarget target = client.target("http://192.168.1.1:8080/");

        String response = target
                .path("wm/acl/rules/json")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .build("DELETE", Entity.entity(model, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .invoke(String.class);

        System.out.println(response);
    }

    private static class Model {
        public int ruleid = 1;
    }
}
```

Note that you need to configure the client with Property `ClientProperties.SUPPRESS_HTTP_COMPLIANCE_VALIDATION = true`. Otherwise you get an Exception: `Entity must be null for http method DELETE.`

You will find many examples on how to build a Java REST client with Jersey. For example: https://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-restful-client-examples/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use POST request instead of DELETE, because body of DELETE request is ignored.
From spec:

*The DELETE method requests that the origin server delete the resource **identified by the Request-URI***

[reference link](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7)