# Running a Java REST API in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, rest, maven

I am trying to follow [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/#initial).

I have downloaded the gs-rest-service project and imported it into my workspace.

Now I would simply like to run the project - whatever I try seems to fail though. Am I right in thinking I would need to deploy this project to a server so I could run it permanently in the background and have it reply to my REST calls? How can I do this?

I have tried running the project in nearly all ways, as a Java Application/Java Applet/Maven Build. All seem to fail.

I am new to Spring and MVN so I realise I am undoubtedly doing something really, really stupid here - if anyone could tell me what that is I would be most appreciative.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Spring Tool Suite](https://spring.io/guides/gs/sts/) plugin for Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

You do not actually need a Spring application to run your web service. You can try the below procedure

1) Create and Run a Rest service

Create a dynamic web project. host it in your application server of your choice. 
follow the link below:
[first application using Rest](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_first_application.htm)

2) Create a Rest Client

Create a new java project -> Create a new Java class to make the rest call

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Form;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public class WebServiceTester  {

   private Client client;
   private String REST_SERVICE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/UserService/users";
   private static final String PASS = "pass";
   private static final String FAIL = "fail";

   private void init(){
      this.client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
      WebServiceTester tester = new WebServiceTester();
      //initialize the tester
      tester.init();
      //test get all users Web Service Method
      tester.testGetUsers();

   }
   //Test: Get list of all users
   //Test: Check if list is not empty
   private void testGetUsers(){
      GenericType<List<User>> list = new GenericType<List<User>>() {};
      List<User> users = client
         .target(REST_SERVICE_URL)
         .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
         .get(list);
      String result = PASS;
      if(users.isEmpty()){
         result = FAIL;
      }
      else{
          for(User each: users){
          System.out.println("user id :"+each.getId());
          System.out.println("user name :"+each.getName());
          System.out.println("user id :"+each.getProfession());
          }

      }
      System.out.println("Test case name: testGetUsers, Result: " + result );


   }

}
```

libraries required to run the above client program

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jersey-client.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jersey-common.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jersey-media-jaxb.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hk2-api-2.4.0-b34.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hk2-locator-2.4.0-b34.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jersey-guava-2.22.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar"/>
```

Comment: The guide you cite is for building a spring app in the form of an executable jar. After you build and run this jar, the greeting service will be available from your browser.

What errors do you get ? There is so many fails possible

Some checks: do you have maven installed correctly, accessible from shell, with environment variables set ?

do you have enough disk space for all dependencies to be downloaded ?

does your eclipse project have the maven facet/aspect ?

did you try mvn spring-boot:run ?