# Consuming a REST Webservice in JAVA which gives output as XML

Tags: xml, web-services, rest, jersey

I need to access a thirdparty REST Webservice via my java class which gives the response in xml format.

How can i write a sample java class to consume this thirdparty REST service?

After googling for several days, I came to an observation that i can consume webservice using Jersey. But still am not sure how can i use Jersey in my scenario as I just need to read the response from a thirdyparty webservice. Please help.

**EDIT:**
I tried using the website http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/
to convert the xml response obtained by the webservice to POJO classes.
But still am not sure what exactly I need to do to proceed further.

Comment: We don't know what you mean by "consume" the output from the service.  Do you need to deserialize it to a POJO? Just parse the XML?  The question is not really clear at all.

Comment: Again i could see  a -1 for this question. I dont understand the reason behind this. Anyway I believe 'consume' is a generic keyword used for webservices and thatz the reason why i used the term here as well. My requirement is that I need to fire a request to a thirdparty rest webservice which gives output in an xml format. My question was how can i parse this response without writing any specific xml parser or something. I believe Jersey with JAXB will help here, but am not sure how can i use this. Most of the questions like this is still unanswered in stackoverflow.

Comment: That's the problem. "Consume" is too generic and we don't know what your ultimate goal is for the returned XML.

Comment: @JimGarrison I need to read the xml response and convert it to Java objects.(I assume i have explained this in the question as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need REST client for Java. There are several ways to implement it, more details can be found at:

- [Rest clients for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221442/rest-clients-for-java)
- Simple REST client in Java - https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/simple-rest-client-in-java.html
- XML Example With Jersey + JAXB - https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/xml-example-with-jersey-jaxb/

Execute request, get response and parse it to your data structure. Jersey client example:

```
Client client = Client.create();

WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/example/rest/service");

ClientResponse clientResponse = webResource.accept("application/xml").post(ClientResponse.class, yourRequestObject);

YourResponseType yourResponse = clientResponse.getEntity(YourResponseType.class);
```

Comment: Thank you @Justas the guidance. Eventhough am too late to answer this (itz almost 22 months i have posted this)  I was able to achieve my requirement by using the following steps: