# How to pull data from xml response in java with Spring boot?

Tags: xml, spring, api, spring-boot, spring-data

Hey guys i need to pull data from an api xml response from Goodreads to my project database how to do that with my spring-boot project , and is there any way to get directly from the browser ?

Comment: Use any Rest Client API http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221442/rest-clients-for-java

Comment: what is the best practice and REST CLIENT to use with Spring boot to learn more about it ?

Comment: RestTemplate is a commonly used Spring API http://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate/ , there is nothing you need to do just because you are running it as spring-boot application