# How can we consume REST and SOAP services in Helidon SE

Tags: java, rest, soap, helidon

How can we consume external REST and SOAP services in Helidon SE.

Comment: Please, edit your question and provide more details on what the exact issue do you have. What did you try and what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not explicitly related to Helidon SE.

Consuming REST or SOAP web services require writing a client, and you can accomplish this goal in several ways.

For REST ws you can refer here [How do you create a REST client for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221442/how-do-you-create-a-rest-client-for-java) .

For SOAP ws here https://www.baeldung.com/java-soap-web-service .

Answer (score 0):

Helidon SE- Web client: https://helidon.io/docs/latest/#/se/webclient/01_introduction

```
//Create a WebClient with simple builder:
WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUri("http://localhost")
        .build();

//Execute a simple GET request to endpoint:
Single<String> response = client.get()
        .path("/endpoint")
        .request(String.class);
```