# Rest api services in Android Studio

Tags: android, api, rest

What is the best way to deal with rest api services (post,get, put, and delete) in Android Studio.
I have an api to check user name and password wokring very well in Postman, as:

```
http://68.183.162.00:8082/api/v1/cattg/login/
```

which accepts and provides JSON array.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are after here. Is the question rather how to consume a REST api in Kotlin? Also I noticed your API doesn't use SSL, which means your network traffic will not be encrypted

Comment: I'm using Java.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you create a REST client for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221442/how-do-you-create-a-rest-client-for-java)

Comment: I think you are looking for retrofit .

Comment: You can also look into [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/)