# ColdFusion oAuth Consumer against PHP Pantheon site

Tags: oauth, coldfusion, pantheon

I am an oAuth newbie and struggling to implement a simple oAuth consumer in ColdFusion against a PHP site which uses the Pantheon oAuth library.  The following curl script works perfectly and returns the JSON I need.

> curl -X POST -i -H "Content-type: application/json" -c cookies.txt -X
>   POST https://example.org/service/user/login?mykeyhere -d
>   '{"username":"myuser","password":"mypassword"}'

My question is how do i implement this in ColdFusion, returning the responding JSON into a variable that I can parse?

Thanks for your help!

Ben

---

UPDATE 5/3/13

Ok, I tried to translate the cURL line and am getting closer - here's what I did:

```
<cfset mydata = serializejson('{"username":"myuser","password":"mypass"}')>

<cfhttp url="https://example.org/service/user/login" method="post" >
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-type" value="application/json" > 
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="oauth_consumer_key"  value="mykey" > 
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value='#mydata#' >
    <cfhttpparam name="cookies.txt" type="cookie" value="" > 
</cfhttp>
```

However, I am still getting a negative response - but it seems it is because I am not passing the values that are in the "-d" clause from the cURL script correctly.   Any ideas?

Thanks again!

---

Latest update:
 Tried both of these to no avail - i also removed the cookie line:

```
<cfset mydata = '{"username":"myuser","password":"mypass"}'>
<cfset mydata = serializejson('{"username=myuser","password=mypass"}')>
```

---

3:20 ET

Sorry - made the correction as per your comment to below - but still no luck:

```
<cfset myData = serializeJSON({username="user",password="pass"})>
```

Comment: It looks like a simple POST request, so the equivalent is [cfhttp](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ffc.html)  with a few [headers/parameters](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d85.html) thrown in ie `Content-Type`, `body`. Start by taking a look at the [cURL manual](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html). Translate the options ie `-X, -i, -H, -d` and see how far you get. Post back with your code if you run into problems.

Comment: Thanks Leigh - any thoughts on the approach I tool?

Comment: The value string looks off. The input string you are using is already in json format. So wrapping it in `serializeJSON` will mangle it. I suspect you meant to use CF's implicit structure notation instead. Note the use of `=` instead of `:`. ie `<cfset myData = serializeJSON({username="myuser",password="mypass"})>`

Comment: Also, I do not think there is a straight translation of the "cookies" stuff in cfhttp. So I would omit that parameter for now.

Comment: Ok - i removed the cookie line and tried both of these to no avail - any other ideas?  Im really stuck - and thanks.....    :  <cfset mydata = '{"username":"user","password":"pass"}'>

 <cfset mydata = serializejson('{"username=user","password=pass"}')>

Comment: Your JSON code is still wrong. Take another look at the `cfset` in my comment above. It should look like this: `<cfset myData = serializeJSON(  {username="myuser",  password="mypass"}  )>`

Comment: Ok - i see it - still no luck - I put the change as per above and a negative.  But again, the cURL works fine?

Comment: I am not familiar with `cURL`, but it seems to have debugging options. I would dump the request (headers and content) and compare it to what [cfhttp is sending](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515452/view-cfhttp-request). Look for differences. That is about all I can suggest for now. Is there a public URL people can test? And/or an online API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great idea on the debugging of the cURL post - I figured it out. It was just about the headers - the data WAS being passed correctly.

Once the JSON is created, here's the CFHTTP call:

```
<cfhttp url="https://mydomain.org/service/user/login?oauth_consumer_key=myKeyHere" method="post" >
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-type" value="application/json" > 
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="*/*" > 
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#mydata#" >
</cfhttp>
```

Works great - thanks to Leigh for helping me think this through!

Comment: Glad you figured it out, and thanks for posting the resolution :)