# How to debug PHP REST Service running on Apache using Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I have a PHP web application that also exposes some REST services. I am unable to debug (set breakpoints, step over, step into code) my REST services. I've found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165720/how-to-debug-restful-services) with a similar title. The solutions pointed out therein are mostly about how to test RESTful services using [RESTClient](http://restclient.net/) or [HTTP4e](http://www.nextinterfaces.com/).

I am able to debug the web application using the built it browser in Eclipse PDT. If I set breakpoints in code and Run->Debug, I am able to hit the breakpoints etc.

For REST services, I'm unable to do this. If I hit Debug, the normal application control flow occurs starting with index.html.

For all my API's I require some authentication headers to be supplied with the request so I'm unable to simulate this using the Debug Configurations settings.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

XDebug uses cookie for debug. So, you should include generated cookie (in browser) into your REST client.

Comment: I am using ZendDebugger. Which cookie are you talking about? I'm trying to debug in eclipse. thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I told about XDebug not ZendDebug.